cp_errordocument.shtml (port 443)
I had an existing website on my hosting service and I created this site with WordPress. I can add more than one site to my hosting service, so I added a new domain name to the same hosting service (I added it to the homepage, not into the public_html folder). I set the nameservers for my domain via cloudflare and forwarded the server domains correctly. I added the WordPress files to the domain name folder I created on Cpanel. Cloudflare SSL
Set to full (strict)
The error I get is

I can view my website address, but my SSL certificate does not appear
I cannot reach wp-admin, I get the error 404 not found websiteurl/cp_errordocument.shtml (port 443)

I reset the cookies but nothing changed, I also checked the .htaccess and there was nothing missing.
